# React-native error: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'

Tags: android, react-native

My React Native build quite suddenly fails with an error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'Driver'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
  > Could not find lint-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.1.2).
 Searched in the following locations:
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/26.1.2/lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar
```

Other questions had to do with

```
Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':react-native-document-scanner:classpath'.
```

This one has the message

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
```